# Centos 7 - no network adapter

Tags: linux, centos

I've just installed centos 7.1 (64 GUI). During installation it showed me no network device (screen where people set languages etc) - I was suprised but continued installation. When I started centos after installation I did the following:

```
ifconfig -a 
nmcli d
```

Both commands showed only lo interface. The network adapter is set because it had worked without any promlems one hour ago (before centos 7 there was centos 6.4). Besides lights on adapter don't blink. However when I do 
`lspci` I see there ethernet controller NVIDEA.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This device uses the forcedeth driver which is disabled in the CentOS 7
kernel.

You can use the kmod-forcedeth driver from elrepo.org:

http://elrepo.org/linux/elrepo/el7/x86_64/RPMS/kmod-forcedeth-0.64-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64.rpm